# Which is the best SIFT feature to use in a particular scenario?

Tags: sift

I know about SIFT features of an image. But The [ImageClef](http://www.imageclef.org/2012/photo-flickr/descriptors) challenge mentions about various SIFT feature descriptors - SIFT, C-SIFT, RGB-SIFT and OPPONENT-SIFT.

I am unable to find any resource which mentions about how these feature descriptors are different. How does each of these feature descriptors differ and how to determine which feature is good for a particular application?